# Python Module to Plot an Average Value on a Map?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm currently analyzing air quality data. I've got long arrays of 17 columns and around 100 rows/day that I'll be averaging. I'd like to plot some of that data, specifically Ozone concentrations, on a map.

Basically, my visualized final product is this:
So, where the air quality sensor is, I want to highlight a 1x1 km area around it in a specific color corresponding to the value of ozone concentration the sensor is reading (either over an average day or at a specific time).

Is there any python module that could help me achieve this product/plot my data onto a map well?

Comment: I think this could be useful https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "Basemap" is a rather popular package for creating maps in Python, I suggest having a look at this article: [How to draw rectangles on a Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251189/how-to-draw-rectangles-on-a-basemap)

Once you figure out how to draw rectangles that are scaled to your specifications, it should be easy to fill them with a color representing your data.

Cheers!